# Can I trust that my libgdx app for android will work on Sdk version 14?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

This is all in the build.gradle for android.

So if I set the minSdkVersion to 13 Android Studio says it's too low, but it seems to be happy if I set it to 14. Is it safe to assume that it will work on sdkVersion 14? Unfortunately I do not have a phone with sdkVersion 14, and I haven't been able to get the emulator working for that version.

My buildToolsVersion is set to 28.0.3

compileSdkVersion is set to 27

targetSdkVersion is set to 27

Also I tried setting up a virtual device of Nexus 4 with API 15 in the android studio AVD manager, but it just has a black screen on the virtual phone and never seems to start up. Anyone had the same problem when trying an emulator with low API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you aren't doing any tricky stuff in your Android module, you'll be fine. There are many games released with LibGDX installed on every version of Android. If there were a problem with specific Android versions, it would have turned up in the LibGDX issue tracker.

By tricky stuff, I mean customizing permissions in the manifest, calling Android code by reflection, etc. Things that have behavior changes across different versions of Android. When you target Android SDK 27, all the Android behavior changes in the various versions between `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` take effect.

OpenGL ES 2.0 is unsupported in old versions of the Android emulator, which is why you get the black screen.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 1 more question, what minsdkversion would you put then? Although android studio warns me, I can even put minsdkversion of 9 and everything compiles still. Should I put minsdkversion 14 or can I go lower?

Comment: I've started targeting 16, partially to weed out very old devices that might simply have performance issues running something that has lots of particle effects on the screen, for example. Barely anything is still running less than 16. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards